# Can't View Apache Test Page Using Ubuntu Server AWS

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-18.04

SOLUTION: I didn't open port 80 in the security groups. Once doing that everything worked.

I have an AWS instance running Ubuntu. I installed Apache and Ngix with the following commands:

```
 sudo apt install apache2 apache2-utils libapache2-mod-python libapache2-mod-php
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo apt install nginx
sudo service nginx stop
sudo service apache2 start
```

From my understanding, if I go to the public DNS of my AWS instance, I should be getting the Apache test page. However, it is just timing out. I viewed /var/www/html and the index.html page is there, along with another .html page.

Is there something else I need to do? Or configure in AWS?

Comment: Nick - Don't edit your question with the solution. Post an answer and then select your answer as the solution. Otherwise you will have an open question on your account and for the tags. Add more details to your answer to make it complete. This will help others with similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open AWS Management Console. Go to Network & Security, then Security Groups. Highlight the correct item, click Inbound on the bottom. Add HTTP on port 80.

Answer (score 0):

You would definitely make sure port 80 is open and allowed.. open meaning your  network rules in aws, allowed meaning ubuntu can use it;
sudo ufw allow 80 does it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).